# psql: error: falló la conexión al servidor en «localhost» (::1), puerto 5432: FATAL: no existe la base de datos «postgres»

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, postgresql, windows, shell

Ayuda por favor. Estoy trabajando con postgres, en windows[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] y la IDE Datagrip. Antes me funcionaba bien y podía acceder a mi DB, pero sinceramente no se que hice y ya no puedo, creo que borre algo que no o borre la DB.

Trate de entrar desde SQL Shell con mi usuario predeterminado(postgres) y mi contraseña que estoy segurísimo que era esa, sin embargo me aparece el error "psql: error: falló la conexión al servidor en «localhost» (::1), puerto 5432: FATAL:  no existe la base de datos «postgres»"

En mi intento por resolverlo, trate de cambiar desde pg_hba en lugar de scram-sha-256 a la palabra trust para que no me pidiera contraseña, pero me sigue saliendo el mismo error. Creo que borre mi DB o algo porque realmente no se que hace. Pensé que se podía borrar todo e iniciar nuevamente, alguien sabe que puedo hacer por favor?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Verificaste que tu servicio de Postgres este iniciado? Si tienes instalado PgAdmin4 (asumo que si) verifica que el servidor se este ejecutando.